# Routing Guidelines for Analog Video (VGA, RGsB, PAL)

Tags: pcb, layout, rgb, routing, vga

I am currently into the design of the analog video IN/OUT. Basically I have a 3U PCB on which the encoder/decoder ICs are present, that converts the digital video to the analog RGsB (RGsB OUT) and PAL out, and from board-to-board connector this signal goes to the backplane where the RGB connectors are present and connects to the RGB display. Similarly from the VGA connector (VGA IN) on the backplane, the analog signals are coming to the main card from the backplane via board-to-board connector.

Now my concerns are:

1. What precautions need to be taken care while designing the circuits that involves the video signals?
2. Routing guidelines as the traces are routed long way from the main board to the backplane and then to the connector where the display will be connected.
3. Do we need to use any sort of amplifier ICs on the analog signal path?

It would be  great if I get good techniques/methods that need to be followed while designing the board/PCB with analog video In/Out, where a backplane is involved and the connectors are far from the encoder/decoder.

Comment: Dont share the 75 ohm signal ground path with any other noise currents.

Comment: What bandwidth is the RGB?

Comment: The IC that generatoes RGsB and PAL out, can you provide a link to this IC? Or manufacturer and P/N? It is not clear whether an additional buffer is reqired or the IC already has a buffer built into. But the main thing you are going to want to do is route the traces with 75 Ohm impedance, and keep clearance to any potential agressor or victim signals along the entire path. It may be necessary or desirable to use 75 Ohm coax from board to board rather than using a board to board connector that lumps video with other digital signals.